# Apache2 shows default page even after disabling it

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, web, server

I've moved a wordpress site to an Ubuntu Server. While I access it from localhost everything works fine but when I try from my public IP address I can only see the apache2 default page.

I tried everything:

- Disabled 000-default.conf and enabled mine
- Deleted the default HTML page
- Added AllowOverride All

Here there's my Virtual Host file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        <Directory "/var/www/exidis">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ServerName alternanza.duckdns.org
        ServerAlias www.alternanza.duckdns.org
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exidis

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion

Comment: try with "curl" to make sure browser cache is not misleading you. Also, don't use .htaccess and ser "AllowOverride none" if you have access to the server config.

Comment: I tried with curl but I have the same problem. Also set AllowOverride None but still got the same problem.

Comment: ping your domain to know if it leading you the right ip you intended to serve from, also do disable any external cdn if you have deployed one. And throw an update here